# SwiftUI Share Sheet Crashes iPad

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiactionsheet

I was following [this tutorial](https://jeevatamil.medium.com/how-to-create-share-sheet-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swiftui-cef64b26f073) to add a simple share sheet to my SwiftUI app. It works properly on iPhones but crashes on iPad with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x107d95ee0>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

Any way to get around this error? Not exactly sure what's happening here.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set `sourceView` and `sourceRect` on the `UIActivityViewController`'s `popoverPresentationController`. Here's a more complete and correct example than I've seen so far:

```
// Get a scene that's showing (iPad can have many instances of the same app, some in the background)
let activeScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene
        
let rootViewController = (activeScene?.windows ?? []).first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController
        
// iPad stuff (fine to leave this in for all iOS devices, it will be effectively ignored when not needed)
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = rootViewController?.view
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = .zero
        
rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to open Actionsheet in iPad.

```
if let vc = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController{
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [urlShare], applicationActivities: nil)
        if isIpad{
            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = vc.view
            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = .zero
        }
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: What is `isIpad`? FYI - there's no reason to only set the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` on an iPad. It's perfectly fine to set them for all devices.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution without any warning, also works on iPad.

```
Button {
    let AV = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Hello World!"], applicationActivities: nil)
    let activeScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene
    let rootViewController = (activeScene?.windows ?? []).first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController
    // for iPad. if condition is optional.
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad{
        AV.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = rootViewController?.view
        AV.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = .zero
    }
    rootViewController?.present(AV, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
     
}
```